# Two records to be updated, but only one gets updated

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning `MongoDB` so I've started reading the documentation and playing around with queries etc.

I have the following collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : 1, "b" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : 2, "b" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : 3, "b" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 4, "a" : 4, "b" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 5, "a" : 5, "b" : 15 }
```

Now if we look at the following query:

```
db.stuff.update( { b : { $gte : 10 } },
                 { $set : { b : 15 } },
                 { multi : true, upsert : true } )
```

How I see the query running is as follows:

1. First check if b is greater than or equal to 10
2. Then set the value of b 15 if its original value is 10 or above
3. multi -  has been specified so it can update more then one record
4. upsert - insert a new document when no other documents match the criteria specified.

Now judging on the documents in the collection already I would expect this to update two records which are:

```
{ "_id" : 4, "a" : 4, "b" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 5, "a" : 5, "b" : 15 }
```

However it only updates one, can someone please explain to me what I've misunderstood here?

Comment: Yes. You misunderstood `nMatched` and `nUpdated`. Two documents "match" but only **one** "updates" because the value is already `15`, so MongoDB says *"nothing to update here!"*. This is by design. If you ran again looking for `$gte: 15` and set the value to `20` then **both** update.

Comment: @NeilLunn oh wow, that's pretty cool to be fair.  Thanks for the info.